# I just moved, have no internet on my laptop or ipod, but everyone else who lives here does

Tags: laptop, internet, connection, ipod

I just moved to Thunder Bay and my laptop as well as my ipod cannot connect to the internet. My laptop allows me to write the password for the wifi, but I still have no internet connection. When I try to use the cable, the computer tells me I have a perfect connection, even the icon shows that it's working, but I can't open any web pages or use any internet functions. When I try to use MSN it sends me to a troubleshooting option and informs me that there's some kind of problem with the "gateway".

I have unplugged the modem and the router and plugged them back in, this did not help. I am living in a home where all the people are using wifi on the same system as me, and no one has ever had any problems.

Back home both my laptop and my ipod worked without a problem both in my home, as well as on campus. Since this problem seems to be limited only to me, it would indicate that there's a problem on my end -- with my laptop. However, in that case my ipod would be working. It has never failed to connect before.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This seems completely ubuntu unrelated. If your iPod has no internet connection either, than it's probably no problem with ubuntu.

You should seek help at someone who lives near you and can help you with troubleshooting these internet problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try some of the network troubleshooting techniques I wrote about in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176344/how-to-solve-wirelesss-router-issues-vs-isp-issues/176392#176392).

Try to ping your gateway.  If you can't do that, then you know there's an issue on your LAN between you and your router.

If that works, next try to ping an Internet IP such as "4.2.2.2".  If it works you're connected to the Internet.

Next try to ping www.google.com.  If that doesn't work, you probably need to check your DNS settings.

Also double check System Settings -> Nework and make sure you're set to use DHCP.

Good luck!